# Безопасно-мутабельно-статический RwLock с Sender внутри [Rust]

Tags: многопоточность, rust

У меня есть 2 потока, отправляющие сообщения, и основной поток их подхватывает.
Для этого я использую `mpsc`. Мне нужно инициализировать его статически. Для этого его нужно сделать его мутабельным. Так как обычные `static mut` являются `unsafe`, я решил его использовать через `lazy_static!` в обертке `Mutex`. Там он по сути является мьютексной ссылкой, которую можно разименовать и дать значение (при этом это все в `safe` Rust'е)

```
use std::sync::{mpsc::*, *};
use std::thread;

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref MAIN_SENDER: Mutex<Option<Sender<u8>>> = Mutex::new(None);
}

fn ae() {
    let tx = MAIN_SENDER.lock().unwrap().clone().unwrap().clone();

    thread::spawn(move || { loop {
        tx.send(23).unwrap();
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(200));
    }});
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    *MAIN_SENDER.lock().unwrap() = Some(tx);
    ae();

    for rex in rx {
        println!("{}", rex);
    }
}
```

Но это работает только для одного потока. Теперь мне нужно это сделать для 2 потоков, которым нужно передать `Sender`, чтобы они по нему отдавали сообщения в главный поток. Я для этого использую `RwLock`, у которого нет ограничений по читателям памяти, но может быть только один писатель. Причем с логической точки зрения, это можно сделать, ибо потоки-дети лишь читают память, в котором храниться `Sender`, и уже по которому они отдельно могут отправлять сообщения, независимо от писателя `RwLock`

```
use std::sync::{mpsc::*, *};
use std::thread;

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref MAIN_SENDER: RwLock<Option<Sender<u8>>> = RwLock::new(None);
}

fn reqs(var: u8) {
    let tx = MAIN_SENDER.read().unwrap().clone().unwrap().clone();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            tx.send(var).unwrap();
            thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(200));
        }
    });
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    *MAIN_SENDER.write().unwrap() = Some(tx);
    reqs(25);
    reqs(14);

    for req in rx {
        println!("{}", req);
    }
}
```

`static ref MAIN_SENDER: RwLock<Option<Sender<u8>>> = RwLock::new(None);`

`<- Error: std::sync::mpsc::Sender<u8> cannot be shared between threads safely`

Ну, я отчетливо понимаю что натягиваю сову на глобус. Но есть ли способ сохранения `Sender` в статическую память в обертке `RwLock`, для обеспечения доступа к нему из `safe` Rust?

Честно говоря, я даже не знаю как написать это через `unsafe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Sender явно размечен, как !Sync, что предполагает его роль в качестве некой обёртки синхронизации доступа, а внутри (при использовании из одного потока) доступ к памяти ведётся напрямую, т.е. представим нарушение подобного инварианта и получим датарейс. Я бы рекомендовал присмотреться к [crossbeam-channel](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-channel/latest/crossbeam_channel/), но если хочется mpsc именно из std, тогда попробуйте такую обёртку.

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5dbe48e7712a46c8fb5a294d46dc1837)

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::ops::DerefMut;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::MutexGuard;
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;
use thread_local::ThreadLocal;

pub struct CowSender<T: Send> {
    original: Mutex<Sender<T>>,
    local: ThreadLocal<Sender<T>>,
}

pub struct CowSenderGuard<'a, T: Send> {
    inner: &'a mut Sender<T>,
    local: &'a mut ThreadLocal<Sender<T>>,
}

impl<T: Send> CowSender<T> {
    pub fn lock_mut(&mut self) -> CowSenderGuard<'_, T> {
        CowSenderGuard {
            inner: self.original.get_mut().unwrap_or_else(|x| x.into_inner()),
            local: &mut self.local,
        }
    }
    
    fn lock_inner(&self) -> MutexGuard<'_, Sender<T>> {
        self.original.lock().unwrap_or_else(|x| x.into_inner())
    }
}

impl<T: Send> Deref for CowSender<T> {
    type Target = Sender<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Sender<T> {
        self.local.get_or(|| self.lock_inner().clone())
    }
}

impl<T: Send> Deref for CowSenderGuard<'_, T> {
    type Target = Sender<T>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Sender<T> {
        &self.inner
    }
}

impl<T: Send> DerefMut for CowSenderGuard<'_, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Sender<T> {
        &mut self.inner
    }
}

impl<T: Send> Drop for CowSenderGuard<'_, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.local.iter_mut().for_each(|local| local.clone_from(&self.inner));
    }
}

pub static SENDER: OnceCell<RwLock<CowSender<u8>>> = OnceCell::new();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я немного почитал по этой теме и решил остановиться на `flume`

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам RwLock? Ведь разделяемый Sender вы используете только для того, чтобы склонировать его, и после клонирования вам уже не нужна блокировка. Тут более чем достаточно мьютекса, и ваше исходное решение должно работать с любым количеством потоков-писателей, а если не работает - ищите ошибку.

---

Однако задумайтесь - зачем вам вообще условно-статическая инициализация и мьютексы?

Всё что вам нужно - это передать один параметр в функцию:

```rust
fn reqs(tx: Sender<u8>, var: u8) {
    thread::spawn(move || { loop {
        tx.send(23).unwrap();
        thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(200));
    }});
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    reqs(tx.clone(), 25);
    reqs(tx, 14);

    for req in rx {
        println!("{}", req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так то да. Тут скорее в целом мои знания по этой теме были не слишком велики. Но просто передать как параметр я не мог - функция предназначалась для вызова из иной среды (игровым движком), и по хорошему должна была вызываться без каких-либо параметров.